# Javascript: How do I access values in nested objects if I don’t know the object’s key?

Tags: javascript, json, object, github, github-api

If I have a Javascript object, parsed from JSON, that’s nested three deep, and I don’t know the key for the middle one, how to I access it and its contents?

The actual data I’m working with is from the Github API. For this example, I want the file names for all my gists.

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/11164200",
    "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/11164200/forks",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/11164200/commits",
    "id": "11164200",
    "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/11164200.git",
    "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/11164200.git",
    "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/11164200",
    "files": {
      "testing.md": {
        "filename": "testing.md",
        "type": "text/plain",
        "language": "Markdown",
        "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/omphalosskeptic/11164200/raw/3582779a4925ea514382cedb7d077d00c231f3eb/testing.md",
        "size": 4254
      }
    }, // [ ... continues]
```

My Javascript skills are rudimentary. Normally I can find what I’m looking for with enough research but not this time. Originally I expected it would be something like: `responseObj[0].files[0].filename`.

If possible I’d like to keep this plain Javascript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sample you posted, the `files` property is not an array, so can't be accessed by an indexer. This is a case where you would use a `for-in` loop rather than a regular `for` loop.

```
for(var p in responseObj[0].files) {                 
  if ( responseObj[0].files.hasOwnProperty (p) ) {   
    p; // p is your unknown property name
    responseObj[0].files[p]; // is the object which you can use to access 
                             // its own properties (filename, type, etc)           
  }                                                                                                           
}
```

The `hasOwnProperty` check will skip the automatic members like `toString` and only return those manually defined on the object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over them, do something like

```
for (var fileID in responseObj[0].files) {
    var file = responseObj[0].files[fileID];
    var filename = file.filename;
}
```

Comment: Using `var` inside a loop gives the false impression that _JavaScript_ has block-level scope.

Comment: It does, but if you don't know that already, moving them outside will not really help your understanding a lot. And if you do know, then you  can consciously ignore moving the `var` declaration at the beginning of the function because it just reads worse. I see where Crockford was coming from, but I don't really see how it helps people who don't even understand what block or function scope mean.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! Unfortunately I don’t have enough rep to upvote your post, and I can only accept one...